# Simplify syntax, how to avoid duplicate "if"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to check a form when fields are error and disabling submit button as appropriate. I found a solution that works, but the syntax is ugly. :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#validatemail").keyup(function()
    {
        var email = $("#validatemail").val();
        if (email != '')
        {
            if(isvalidmail(email))
            {
                // do stuff
            }
            else
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        else
        {
                // do stuff
        }
    });
    $("#validatetitle").keyup(function()
    {
        var subject = $("#validatetitle").val();
        if (subject != '')
        {
            if ((subject.length < 3) || (subject.length > 30))
            {
                // do stuff
            }
            else
            {
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        else
        {
                // do stuff
        }
    });
    $("#form_message").live('keyup', function()
    {
        // Duplicate is not smart!!!
            var email = $("#validatemail").val(); // Duplicate
            var subject = $("#validatetitle").val(); // Duplicate
            if (
            (isvalidmail(email)) // Duplicate
            &&
            (!((subject.length < 3) || (subject.length > 30))) // Duplicate
            )
            {       
                $("#send").removeAttr("disabled");  
            }
            else
            {
                $("#send").attr("disabled", "disabled");                
            }
    });
});
```

So how to simplify the code?

I spent several hours trying, but it did not work.

Thank you very much.

Regards,

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isEmailValid = false;
    var isSubjectValid = false;
    $("#send").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#validatemail").keyup(function()
    {
        var email = $("#validatemail").val();
        if (email != '')
        {
            if(isvalidmail(email))
            {
                // do stuff
                isEmailValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // do stuff
                isEmailValid = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                // do stuff
        }
    });
    $("#validatetitle").keyup(function()
    {
        var subject = $("#validatetitle").val();
        if (subject != '')
        {
            if ((subject.length < 3) || (subject.length > 30))
            {
                // do stuff
                isSubjectValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // do stuff
                isSubjectValid = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                // do stuff
        }
    });
    $("#form_message").live('keyup', function()
    {
            // now just get all the set values here
            $("#send").attr("disabled",(isEmailValid && isSubjectValid) ? "" : "disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: @vivek: cannot help your eyesight pal :)

Comment: yes that's true....you can't:)...but at least you should place some comments over there...any way but i think he want to get rid of if statements not with variable he used in those if statements...

Comment: @vivek: did you just downvote me? could you spell out the reasons also?

Comment: you can see at your post there is no downVote against your answer...and i don't think so that i am interesting to loose my 2 points for this answer..

Comment: @vivek: once you reach 1000 points you can click and see the split view of upvote and downvote. its actually +1 and -1

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, accurate and educational. It works. My code is more elegant now.Yes, I wanted to get rid of if statements.

Comment: @yetanothercoder I'm sorry it was me that down-voted I looked at your code and so no difference with the OP's I've changed for a positive vote, my apologies!

Comment: @Trufa: no probs. I was also to blame as my code was not that readable. @Vivek: thanks vivek. @vincent: you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

best way is to `declare and initialize those variable globally` and then use it ...and things which are being repeated in if condition `place them in function` and call it where you have to check those condition...

Comment: Thank you, but I pulled the hair for a long time to solve this problem! So I'll settle for a simple solution like as proposed by yetanothercoder, I am able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document)
.ready(function () {
$("#send")
    .attr("disabled", "disabled"), $("#validatemail")
    .keyup(function () {
    var a = $("#validatemail")
        .val();
    a != "" && isvalidmail(a)
}), $("#validatetitle")
    .keyup(function () {
    var a = $("#validatetitle")
        .val();
    a != "" && (3 > a.length || a.length > 30)
}), $("#form_message")
    .live("keyup", function () {
    var a = $("#validatemail")
        .val(),
        b = $("#validatetitle")
            .val();
    !isvalidmail(a) || 3 > b.length || b.length > 30 ? $("#send")
        .attr("disabled", "disabled") : $("#send")
        .removeAttr("disabled")
})
})
```